# Meteor & Polymer 1.0 - Template.dynamic using helper is not working

Tags: meteor, polymer, meteor-blaze, polymer-1.0

I am trying to play around mixing Polymer (1.0) & Meteor (1.1.0.2). I am trying to use Template.dynamic (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) and trying to set the value of template name using helpers as `{{> Template.dynamic template=whichMainPanelHelper }}` I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at Error (native)
    at DOMRange.detach (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:512:24)
    at DOMRange.setMembers (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:471:12)
    at doMaterialize (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2019:22)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:12)
    at doRender (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2015:17)
    at https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1865:18
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:12)
    at https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1864:29
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2197:12)
globalClient.js?2215a2ab608267b0be3f49b7779cbbe0e07bea5b:4 helper : whichMainPanel : drawerPanelMain
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at Error (native)
    at DOMRange.detach (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:512:24)
    at DOMRange.setMembers (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:471:12)
    at doMaterialize (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2019:22)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:12)
    at doRender (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2015:17)
    at https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1865:18
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:12)
    at https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1864:29
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2197:12)
```

I have done a repo in Cloud 9 @ https://ide.c9.io/rohanray/socioui

can be checked live @ https://socioui-rohanray.c9.io

Comment: @juergen-fink Can you please have a look at this issue?

Comment: can you post the code to a gist or something where I don't have to log in?